# How to update squid proxy 3.5 in Centos 6?

Tags: centos, proxy, squid

I am using Centos 6.6 with 32 bit OS. Now I want to update squid proxy from 3.1 to 3.5. Is it possible to update in centos 6.6? If it is possible, please tell me how to update it.

Answer (score 2):

Peace be upon you:

`cat /etc/yum.repos.d/SQUID.repo`

```
[squid] 
name=Squid repo for CentOS 6 
baseurl=http://www1.ngtech.co.il/rpm/centos/6/x86_64 #go to "http://www1.ngtech.co.il/rpm/centos/6/" and view which architecture is right for you
failovermethod=priority 
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

> yum clean all
>   yum repolist
>   yum update

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the [supported packaged on Centos 6.6](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/), it looks like the highest supported Squid version is 3.4.14.

If you want to update to 3.5 you need to use the unofficial repository identified in Dmitriy's answer and here in the [Squid 3.5 documentation](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/CentOS#Squid-3.5):